# How to print one word by adding new character on each line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to do the following:
The string 'London' needs to be printed acording to this logic:
'L'
'Lo'
'Lon'
'Lond'
'Londo'
'London'

An array or loop is what I have in mind, but a can't get it right. Someone who can help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt (code, etc.) and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: What did you tried? We can't make your homework.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was my first question and now I know how to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop would do it.
Use Array.prototype.slice (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the wanted portion of the string.

```
const string = 'London';
for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    console.log(string.slice(0,i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A easy way of using substring method.

```
const str = "LONDON";
for (let i =0; i<= str.length ;){
  console.log(str.substring(0,i++));
}
```

You may found it strange with using i <= str.length because str.substring(0,0) return empty string "",
You can change to :

```
const str = "LONDON";
for (let i =0; i< str.length ;){
  console.log(str.substring(0,++i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two for loops. One to iterate through all the positions of "London", and the other to iterate through portions of the word "London". Take a look at the code snippet bellow:

```js
var word = "London";
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  var str = "";
  for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    str += word[j];
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will be work fine for your problem.

```
var a = "LONDON";  
a = a.split('');
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   str += a[i];
   console.log(str);
}
```

Happy Coding!!